# how to show a confirmation message on any link clicked in a mailitem in vsto outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I want to show a confirmation message before redirecting or opening the link when anyone clicked on a link in mail item either the explorer window or inspector window.
Is it possible ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Word (which renders messages in Outlook) does not expose any events that fire when a user clicks on a link.

Comment: then there is any other way or not ? yeah I searched alot for this type of event but I found nothing.

Comment: Event like before redirecting to that link (URL). can we stop it with a confirmation message ?